# Jquery UI initially hide slider handle

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have set up a slider with jquery ui. I want the handle of the slider to be hidden initially and only show up, after the user clicks on the slider. I managed to hide the handle by setting display to none in the ui-slider-handle class. However, I am not able to change it back later on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour To help with the question, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code snippet, based on https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/ example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    start: function() {
      $(".ui-slider-handle", this).show();
    }
  });
  var sw = $("#slider").slider("widget");
  $(".ui-slider-handle", sw).hide();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div>
```

Yes, you can hide the handle with CSS, to make it appear again would just mean over riding the CSS with an element style:

```
$(".ui-slider-handle").css("display", "block");
```

The example above is a bit more specific, yet essentially does the same thing. Once the Slider is initialized, you can call the `widget` method to access the various elements. We can use `.hide()` on the handle. When the User clicks on the Slider, this triggers the `start` event and we can `.show()` the handle at that time.

If you have multiple sliders, the `ui-slider-handle` class might be too ambiguous, so using the selector context will help.

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so `$( "span", this )` is equivalent to `$( this ).find( "span" )`.

See More:

- https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-widget
- https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-start
- https://api.jquery.com/show/
- https://api.jquery.com/hide/
- https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context